# A small question regarding to the maximum of random variables

Tags: probability, statistics

It is just a small question and I will explain where I cannot really get.

I am well aware that $\ P(Y<x)=P(X_1<x)P(X_2<x)\cdots P(X_n<x) $ where

$Y$ is the RV which is the maximum of $X_i$

In between the steps before iid is exploited, how do i get from $\ P(\max(X_1,X_2,\ldots,X_n)<x)$ to

$\ P(X_1<x,X_2<x,\ldots,X_n<x)$? How does this actually satisfy? I would very appreciate if anyone of you could walk me through this thanks!

Comment: Forget probabilities for a moment and think about how to get from $\max(X_1,\ldots,X_n)<x$ to $(X_1<x,X_2<x,\ldots,X_n<x).$ You need to show that those two statements both say the same thing. $\qquad$

Answer (score 2):

$$\max(X_1, X_2, \ldots, X_n) < x \iff X_1 < x \cap X_2 < x \cap \ldots \cap X_n < x$$

$$\implies P(\max(X_1, X_2, \ldots, X_n) < x) = P(X_1 < x, X_2 < x, \ldots, X_n < x)$$

If $X_i, i \in \{1,2,\ldots, n\}$ are independent,

$$P(X_1 < x, X_2 < x, \ldots, X_n < x) = \prod_{i=1}^{n} P(X_i < x)$$

Now, if $X_i, i \in \{1,2,\ldots, n\}$ are identical also, then,

$$P(X_i < x) = P(X_1 < x)$$

Comment: is first line just a fact? that was what I was trying to understand like why

Comment: @natsu, it is very easy to prove. (i) Assume the l.h.s., then for any $i$, $X_i\le\max(X_1,\dots,X_n)<x$; (ii) assume the r.h.s. and note that each of the $X_i$ is less than $x$, so that in particular $\max(X_1,\dots,X_n)<\max(x,\dots,x)=x$.

Comment: @Ian I was writing a similar proof. My proof was based on contradiction. But I think your proof is reasonable too.

Comment: that makes sense but how does it proof the equivlance though? sorry for asking

Comment: we need to prove $p \iff q$. For $p \implies q$, we will prove $\sim q \implies \sim p$, so, assume that atleast one of $X_i \geq x$ and others are less than $x$, then, $X_i \geq x \implies max(X_1, \ldots, X_n) \geq x \
 \ (=\sim p)$. Similarly, prove $q \implies p$.

Answer (score 1):

For numbers:

The largest of $n$ numbers is less than $x$ *if and only if* all each and every one of the numbers is less than $x$.

For random variables:

The probabilistic event that largest of values taken by $n$ random variables is less than $x$ *if and only if* it happens that all each and every one of the value taken by the random variables is less than $x$.